# Binding textbox to ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding, observablecollection

I'm trying to get bind a textbox text property to an observable collection, and report changes back to the collection. The ContactLog property gets set from the calling page.
This is what I have, but it doesn't work.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class cCustomerContactLogFull
    Property ContactLog As ocContactLogs

End Class

Public Class ocContactLogs
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Private _ContactLogID As Integer
    Private _CustomerID As Integer
    Private _ContactMsg As String

    Private _Changed As Boolean

    Private _ContactLogIDChanged As Boolean
    Private _CustomerIDChanged As Boolean
    Private _ContactMsgChanged As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal contactlogid As Integer, ByVal customerid As Integer, ByVal contactmsg As String)

        _ContactLogID = contactlogid
        _CustomerID = customerid
        _ContactMsg = contactmsg

        _Changed = False

        _ContactLogIDChanged = False
        _CustomerIDChanged = False
        _ContactMsgChanged = False
    End sub

    Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal Propertyname As String)
        If Not Propertyname.Contains("Changed") Then
            Changed = True
        End If
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(Propertyname))
    End Sub

    Public Property Changed() As Boolean
        Get
            Return _Changed
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            If _Changed <> value Then
                _Changed = value
                OnPropertyChanged("Changed")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ContactLogID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _ContactLogID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            If _ContactLogID <> value Then
                _ContactLogID = value
                OnPropertyChanged("ContactLogID")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property CustomerID() As Integer
        Get
            Return _CustomerID
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            If _CustomerID <> value Then
                _CustomerID = value
                OnPropertyChanged("CustomerID")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property ContactMsg() As String
        Get
            Return _ContactMsg
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            If _ContactMsg <> value Then
                _ContactMsg = value
                OnPropertyChanged("ContactMsg")
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="cCustomerContactLogFull"
             x:Name="cCustomerContactLogFull"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             DataContext="ContactLog"
             d:DesignHeight="385" d:DesignWidth="657" Height="482" Width="657">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="ScrollViewer1" Margin="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding ContactMsg}" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtContactMsg" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Whats the right way to bind this?

**UPDATE**
This is what I'm hoping to do, except without the listview/itemscontrol

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="centralTile">
        <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke" Width="290" Margin="0,0,0,5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="400*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContactShort}" Margin="0,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" Margin="0,3,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShortMsg}" Margin="10,3,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <l:PlainView x:Key="tileView" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource centralTile}" ItemWidth="300" />
</UserControl.Resources>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=cCustomerContactInfo, Path=contactlogs}" View="{StaticResource tileView}" Name="lstContactLogs" Margin="0,0,5,28" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" />
```

**Solution**

Ok, learning how to properly use DataContext, this appears to work, and it's two way, so bonus.

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="cCustomerContactLogFull"
             x:Name="cCustomerContactLogFull"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="385" d:DesignWidth="657" Height="482" Width="657">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="textBoxTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="100"></TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="checkBoxTemplate">
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value}" IsThreeState="False"></CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="icl">
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Name="ScrollViewer1" Margin="2" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ContactMsg}" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtContactMsg" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Code Behind:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class cCustomerContactLogFull
    Property CustomerID As Integer
    Property ContactLog As ocContactLogs

    Private Sub cCustomerContactLogFull_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        If Not ContactLog Is Nothing Then
            icl.DataContext = ContactLog
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Only use the visual-studio tag if the question actually has anything to do with it.

Comment: It's written in visual studio... I'll leave it out in the future. So I should just use vb.net tag? Are tag use rules spelled out anywhere so I don't make other mistakes?

Comment: They aren't any such rules as far as i know, just think about whether the tag has any relevance for the question. Here that is not the case, if for example the VS designer were to fail and the question is about how to fix that then the tag would be justified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set your DataContext to the string `"ContactLog"`. This is probably not what you want - you should create and set your DataContext in code, probably in the constructor.

Comment: I don't have a problem doing it that way, and this code doesn't work anyway. I've been able to use ItemSource to bind textboxes to observablecollections in listview, itemscontrol, etc, but doing it straight to a textbox without using one of those containers is new. How should I do it right?

Comment: What exactly do you expect/want? How should the application know how tp turn an ObservableCollection into text?

Comment: I updated the question with an example of what I'm hoping to do. I just don't want to have to use the listview.

Comment: Still don't understand it, sorry. Can't you describe it in words?

Comment: Ok, figured out what you meant with the Datacontext in code behind. Wonder why you can't do it in XAML? Not that it's a big deal, just interesting.

Comment: You can do it in XAML, but the DataContext can be anything so it will interpret it as a String if you set it like this, you can write it as element though, e.g.: `<UserControl.DataContext><local:LogMessage /></UserControl.DataContext>`